# how to update a specific value inside a json string using python?

Tags: python, json

There is a json file as follows:

```
{  
     "section_1":
        {
            "setion_id": 1,
            "status": "false"
        }
     "section_2":
        {
            "setion_id": 2,
            "status": "false"
        }
      "section_3":
        {
            "setion_id": 3,
            "status": "false"
        }
      "section_4":
        {
            "setion_id": 4,
            "status": "false"
        }
        ...
    }
```

The file has sections which will vary, I need to update the field status to `true` within the sections.
How do I update the status field to `true` within the sections with even `section_id`?

Comment: It's just a Python dictionary once decoded. What have you tried and what didn't work for you?

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understand your question right.

```
import json

mydict = json.loads("""
{
  "section_1":
    {
      "setion_id": 1,
      "status": "false"
    },
 "section_2":
    {
      "setion_id": 2,
      "status": "false"
    },
  "section_3":
    {
      "setion_id": 3,
      "status": "false"
    },
  "section_4":
    {
      "setion_id": 4,
      "status": "false"
    }
}
""")

for sec in mydict:
    if int(sec.split('_')[1]) % 2 == 0:
        mydict[sec]['status'] = 'true'

print mydict
```

Edit - explanation:
[split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) dict key by "_" to get number of section and with [modulo operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html?highlight=modulo#binary-arithmetic-operations) check if remainder from the division is zero i.e. number is even.

Comment: While the answer is technically correct, an explanation and some references would be helpful for the OP and other people googling it.

Comment: OK I add explanation with references.

Answer (score 0):

```
# lets assume data is in data.json file with the following data
[{  
     "section_1":
        {
            "setion_id": 1,
            "status": "false"
        },
     "section_2":
        {
            "setion_id": 2,
            "status": "false"
        },
      "section_3":
        {
            "setion_id": 3,
            "status": "false"
        },
      "section_4":
        {
            "setion_id": 4,
            "status": "false"
        }

}]
```

you can do this

```
data=open("data.json").read()
# print help(json.load)
# print data
json_str =  json.loads(data)[0]

# for section in json_str:
for section in json_str:
    if json_str[section]["setion_id"] %2==0:
        json_str[section]["status"]="true"
print json_str
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this a solution will help you.

```
In [38]: var = '{"section_1":{"setion_id":1,"status":"false"},"section_2":{"setion_id":2,"status":"false"},"section_3":{"setion_id":3,"status":"false"},"section_4":{"setion_id":4,"status":"false"}}'

In [39]: json_file = json.loads(var) #converting string into json object

In [40]: temp_dic = dict(json_file) #converting json object into python dictionary 

In [41]: temp_dic.update({'section_1':{'section_id':1,'status': 'true'}}) #update dictionary accoding to your need

In [42]: output_json = json.loads(json.dumps(temp_dic)) #converting dictionary into python string

In [43]: output_json
Out[43]: 
{u'section_1': {u'section_id': 1, u'status': u'true'},
 u'section_2': {u'setion_id': 2, u'status': u'false'},
 u'section_3': {u'setion_id': 3, u'status': u'false'},
 u'section_4': {u'setion_id': 4, u'status': u'false'}}
```